# Case in where clause not working in Teradata

Tags: sql, where-clause, teradata

Trying to execute this query but it's not filtering as per the where clause. Please help me to fix this query.

```sql
select  ( cast(current_date as date) + cast( ( -150 ) as INTERVAL DAY(4) ) ),
    case 
        when "a11"."r_date" <> '  ' then (substr(r_date, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(r_date, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(r_date, 1, 4)) end  "CustCol_52"
from    "d_table"   "a11"
where   
    case 
        when "a11"."r_date" <> '  ' then (substr(r_date, 5, 2) 
|| '/' || substr(r_date, 7, 2) 
|| '/' || substr(r_date, 1, 4)) end > '( cast(current_date as date) + cast( ( -150 ) as INTERVAL DAY(4) ) )'
group by    
    case 
        when "a11"."r_date" <> '  ' then (substr(r_date, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(r_date, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(r_date, 1, 4)) end
```

Not sure why the where clause is not filtering the data.

Comment: `> '( cast(current_date...`  - should this really be a string literal?

Comment: Anyway, repeating same somewhat complex case expression several times tend to be a bit risky. A small difference/change can make a huge difference. I'd write it _once_, in a derived table - to simplify and make code more robust.

Comment: @jarlh not sure what other way to write this. This is a query I am trying to fix but not able to.

Comment: You are building a string out  a date, I think 'MM/DD/YYYY', and then trying to compare it to an actual date that you are trying to enclose in single quotes?  This will never work.  What it the data type of `r_date`?  Why can't you just compare that to the current date -150 days?

Comment: @Andrew r_date is char

Comment: ...`Where To_Date(r_date, 'YYYYMMDD') > current_date - Interval 150 Days` should do it.

Comment: Edit your post to show a sample.